# Event -> Find Participants displays event id, not event name in event name field

Tags: civievent

Selecting Events -> Find Participants under CiviCRM 5.1.2, Joomla 3.8.8, PHP 7.2.5 under IIS displays the event ID and not event name in the Event Name field.  This is a bug introduced after 4.7.31.  It may be relevant, but the CiviCRM menu drop downs also disappear.

4.7.31:

[image]

5.1.2:

[image]

I've tried looking at what has changed, but the obvious files aren't showing any such changes.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue on 5.1.2. Could try after deleting template_c and also clear CiviCRM cache

Comment: Strange, I cleared the caches and everything under ../media/civicrm/templates_c except the directory en_GB, but to no avail.  I even reset the custom paths to eliminate custom code.  Are you sure it was on a Joomla instance that you tested it?

Comment: Has anyone tried the update under Joomla?  I updated a local Drupal installation and the problem doesn't appear.  Is that why @PradeepNayak couldn't reproduce the problem?  Is Joomla still supported, or should we move our CiviCRM environment to Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to a general issue with updating CiviCRM under Joomla in a non-US environment, where the views are not updating correctly.  The error was only flagged up when I tried to create an event.  This pointed me to the log file that then showed what the issue was.

I solved the issue by adding the following lines to the definition of, in our case, the view civicrm_uf_group_en_GB:

```
   `civicrm_uf_group`.`frontend_title_en_GB` AS `frontend_title`,
    `civicrm_uf_group`.`cancel_button_text_en_GB` AS `cancel_button_text`,
    `civicrm_uf_group`.`submit_button_text_en_GB` AS `submit_button_text`
```

It seems that the update process isn't applying that change.  My knowledge of the update process isn't sufficient to work out how to do it automatically.

Comment: Are you certain this is Joomla related rather than multilingual related?

Comment: You are probably right - it is multilingual related, but it may have manifested itself in Joomla rather than Drupal (or maybe it is because I was upgrading from a much older system in Drupal).  In general, I have seen a number of issues in the views after upgrading to a new version of CiviCRM which have required manual intervention.